# Load single image on multiple surface of BoxGeometry - Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I am using three.js for creating 3D Objects. I want to create 3d canvas similar like [this](https://www.fiverr.com/hadkarbhushan/convert-your-2d-canvas-image-into-a-3d-canvas-mockup) in my project.
I want to render a single image on all side of object (box) except back.

I have found one similar example here:
https://www.geofx.com/graphics/nehe-three-js/lessons17-24/lesson17/lesson17.html.

I am planing to [BoxGeomatry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/BoxGeometry) along with 2D faceVertexUvs (custom alignment) to cover surfaces.Is there any way I can do it easily rather than managing Vector2 (2D)? Any way I can use Vector3 (3D) or provide pixel to manage easily?

As I am new to Threejs, please suggest better approach if any?

Comment: Manipulating with vertex uvs is not a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with uvs of `BoxBufferGeometry`:

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js";
import {OrbitControls} from "https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 100);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var g = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(10, 5, 1);
var uv = g.getAttribute("uv");

// +x
uv.setXY(0, 1, 1);
uv.setXY(1, 0.9, 1);
uv.setXY(2, 1, 0);
uv.setXY(3, 0.9, 0);

// -x
uv.setXY(4, 0.1, 1);
uv.setXY(5, 0, 1);
uv.setXY(6, 0.1, 0);
uv.setXY(7, 0, 0);

// +y
uv.setXY(8,  0, 0.8);
uv.setXY(9,  1, 0.8);
uv.setXY(10, 0, 1);
uv.setXY(11, 1, 1);

// -y
uv.setXY(12, 0, 0);
uv.setXY(13, 1, 0);
uv.setXY(14, 0, 0.2);
uv.setXY(15, 1, 0.2);

// -z ("back") - white area from 0,0 of map
uv.setXY(20, 0, 0);
uv.setXY(21, 0, 0);
uv.setXY(22, 0, 0);
uv.setXY(23, 0, 0);

var m = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("https://threejs.org/examples/textures/uv_grid_opengl.jpg")});
var o = new THREE.Mesh(g, m);
scene.add(o);

renderer.setAnimationLoop(()=>{
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
</script>
```